# Android App Link not working on Nfc Background tapping, opening in Browser instead of App

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-nfc-manager

I have integrated NFC manager in React Native. when I tap Nfc card, I want to  open the url in the App installed.
I have done everything required, added respective intent  in AndroidManifest.xml and also added assetlinks.json file in https://your-domain.com/.well-known/ location. checked and verified, did clean and rebuild project but still on background tapping its opening in browser instead of app. what can i do more?

Answer (score 1):

In this issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/208483340 google guy answered that NFC and AppLinks don't work together.

I gave up looking for solution.

At least you can create `intent-filter` for NFC

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="example.com"
                android:path="/examplePath" />
</intent-filter>
```

It will open system dialog with apps that can open url in NFC tag